# How can I improve the question about plants?

Tags: support, specific-question

My question of the day
is https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/112096/if-humans-and-animals-perform-their-actions-with-their-brains-how-do-plants-per. The question may have not received close votes so far, but the question has got 4 downvotes. I have temporarily deleted the question to prevent it from getting closed. But what further improvements would be required to prevent that question about plants from getting close votes and downvotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions here are best received when they're supported by prior research.

Questions that are most problematic are those that ask about something that doesn't exist, often requesting "why" something exists without the question showing it does, or "how" something works without the question showing it does - there's not really a good way to answer these. Here, you're asking about an analogy for something that doesn't really have an analogous feature, so answers are either going to be statements like "plants don't have brains" (which isn't very useful) or very opinion-based answers along the lines of "well, if you're willing to stretch the meaning *this* far, I can make a stretch argument for X" - also not very useful.

Comment: @ArunabhBhattacharya Probably better to start by *reading about* plants, and then ask when you get to something you can't quite understand; your questions will work better when you have something to base them on after trying to learn on your own.

Answer (score 5):

One of the problems is with your **title**. I cannot see the completion but it was something like:

> If humans and animals perform their actions with their brains how do
> plants per[form actions in response to stimuli?]

(My completion in [])

**What is wrong with this?** 
A general criticism is that it is too long, including unnecessary parts of your argument or preamble. However the biggest problem is that that argument/preamble includes a comparison of plant responses to those initiated by the brains of animals. It is common knowledge that plants do not have brains, so without reading further than your title, your question appears naïve and slightly ridiculous.

**How could you correct this?** 
Write a simple title. It does not have to be a  sentence even, and should not try to summarize the content of your question. A title is a title and a question is a question. So I would suggest something like:

> Responses of plants to external stimuli

And in your question I would make any comparison with animals quite incidental:

> “As plants do not have brains, how do they…”

**But there is still a problem**
Your question is too wide, in my opinion. You should provide one specific example of a stimulus — light, water, touch etc. — and stick to that. And by that token you should demonstrate that you have tried to obtain the answer yourself by a simple internet search of the type, “How do plants grow towards the light?”, and make it clear what part of the information you have found does not answer your question.